# Adding style element to SVG in Vue component

Tags: vue.js, svg

I'm writing a Vue component that dynamically renders an SVG. Usually `<style>` tags are not allowed in Vue templates, but is there any way to allow it in this particular situation?

The following will either throw an error, or generate an svg *without* the style tag, depending on how your project is setup ([Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-kare-ffwsv?file=/src/App.vue)):

```
<template>
  <svg :width="svgWidth" :height="svgHeight">
    <style>rect{fill:red}</style>
    <rect :height="rectHeight" :width="rectWidth" />
  </svg>
</template>
```

One obvious workaround is to use inline styling for all elements, but for convenience I wonder if it possible to tell Vue to leave the style tag inside the `svg` tag alone?
(I'm generating both style and SVG elements dynamically, so it would make for a more readable code *and* a much smaller rendered SVG element.)

I'd like to make the SVG self-contained, i.e. keeping the style tag *inside* the rendered image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `<style>` tags with svgs, you can prefix them by `svg:`.

Working example:

```html
<template>
  <svg width="100" height="100">
    <svg:style>rect{fill:red;}</svg:style>
    <svg:rect width="20" height="30" />
  </svg>
</template>
```

Please note that I changed the attributes of your `rect` as it displayed an empty (0x0) rectangle.

Comment: Wow, that was easy, thank you! Do you happen to have a link to the documentation on this?

Comment: I just though I would use a namespace to prefix the style tag. Take a look at this: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html#Namespace